# Markov inequality with $>$ in place of $\geq$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The usual Markov inequality goes as follows: suppose $X$ is a random variable with $g \geq 0$. Then for any $r > 0$, 
$$\mathbb{P}(g(X) \geq r) \leq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]}{r}\text{.}$$
Does the following statement still hold true?

$$\mathbb{P}(g(X) > r) < \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]}{r}\text{.}$$

For context, suppose $\mathbb{E}[|X|] = 0$ and we want to find $\mathbb{P}(X > 1)$. A solution I read said that since $\mathbb{P}(X > 1) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X| > 1)$, we can show $\mathbb{P}(X > 1) = 0$ using the above.

I understand how the Markov inequality led to $\mathbb{P}(X > 1) = 0$, but I'm not comfortable using it in the $>$ case without justification.

Comment: The accepted answer below hinges on the possibility that $$P(g(X)\geqslant r)=\frac{E(g(X))}r$$ This happens if and only if the always true inequality $$r\mathbf 1_{g(X)\geqslant r}\leqslant g(X)$$ is an almost sure equality, which, in turn, happens if and only if $$P(g(X)\in\{0,r\})=1$$ Thus, in contradiction to what the answer below asserts, the strict inequality that the question is asking about, does hold in general, that is, except in the precisely delimited case given above. (Yet another example of the "advantages" of instantly accepting answers, after 7 minutes in the present case.)

Answer (score 3):

The strict inequality will not be true in general, because it could be that $\mathbb{P}(g(X)>r)=\mathbb{P}(g(X)\geq r)=\frac{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]}{r}$.

But you can say that $\mathbb{P}(g(X)>r)\leq \mathbb{P}(g(X)\geq r)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]}{r}$, which should be enough for most applications.

Comment: See comment on main.

Comment: @Did: If $X=0$ a.s. and $r>0$, then $\mathbb{P}(X>r)=\mathbb{P}(X\geq r)=0=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{r}$. So equality can hold.

Comment: Note that this is precisely the case of the example in the question.

Comment: Please let us not play on words, shall we? We all know that using Markov to estimate $P(X>1)$ when $X=0$ almost surely is... well, an odd idea. On the other hand, to state that $P(g(X)\geqslant r)=E(g(X))/r$ may happen is true but missing the point. If you were not aware that the only situation where the equality holds is when $P(X\in\{0,r\})=1$, you unwillingly misled the OP. If you knew it and did not mention the fact, you willingly misled them.

Comment: (I wonder what is this virus that makes some users so fanatically attached to everything they post on the site that they seem willing to go to any extent to avoid recognizing they missed a mathematical point...)

Comment: "We all know that using Markov to estimate $P(X>1)$ when $X=0$ almost surely is an odd idea"... and yet this is apparently what the solution OP is referring to did.

Comment: And in such cases, what an answer should provide first and foremost are some explanations of the reasons why the idea is odd, not a false confirmation of the wrong concepts the OP came to believe in. Obvious, no? And to think that such trivialities must be argued about...

Comment: @carmichael561 Question: It seems to me though that if $\Pr[g(X) > r] = \Pr[g(x) \ge r]$, then we can't have $\Pr[g(X) \ge r] = \frac{E[g(x)]}{r}$. This being because for $\Pr[g(X) > r] = \Pr[g(x) \ge r]$ to be true, we must have $\Pr[g(X) = r] = 0$. Therefore there is no weight on $r$; all the weight must be on values strictly greater then $r$. Therefore it seems to me that $r \cdot \Pr[g(X) \ge r] < E[g(x)]$ because of the formula for how we calculate the expected value. This is just my intuition though, so I'm probably missing something...

Comment: @carmichael561I just realized that my argument wouldn't work in the case where $X$ is continuous since in that case $Pr[g(X) > r] = \Pr[g(x) \ge r]]$ whether or not there is nonzero weight on $r$. But it still seems to me that it does work in the discrete case.

Answer (score -1):

It does hold true iff $g(X) = 0$ does not hold almost surely. Here is a short proof:

$$
  \mathbb{E}[g(X)] \\= \mathbb{P}(g(X) \leq r) \mathbb{E}[g(X)|g(X) \leq r] + \mathbb{P}(g(X) > r) \mathbb{E}[g(X)|g(X) > r] \\> g(r) \mathbb{P}(g(X) > r)
$$

The last inequality holds since either $\mathbb{P}(g(X) > r) > 0$ or the first term (and the whole expression) will simply be $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] > 0$. Dividing by $g(r)$ yields $\mathbb{P}(g(X) > r) < \frac{\mathbb{E}[g(X)]}{g(r)}$.